# Are there any client-side tools that allow you to autofill someone's city and state in an HTML form based on their Zip Code?

Tags: html, forms, autofill, zipcode

Are there any client-side tools that allow you to autofill someone's city and state in an HTML form based on their Zip Code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ziptastic will solve your problem
http://daspecster.github.com/ziptastic/

For example, zip.elevenbasetwo.com/?zip=10001 responds with {"country": "US", "state": "NY", "city": "NEW YORK"}

Answer (score 0):

Here is Javascript code that does this - http://zipcodedistanceapi.redline13.com/Examples